# Woocommerce shortcode display on sale products for a specific product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

I have different categories but I want to have an item in my site menu where I will show products on sale in a specific category only instead of all products that are on sale.

I use this code but it shows all products on sale

```
[sale_products per_page="32"]
```

any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom shortcode based on woocommerce version 3.2 exiting shortcodes that will get dynamically the current product category (in single product pages) and will display "on sale" products for it. You can define a specific product category too.

You can also set (inside the function code or in the shortcode itself) this arguments:

- `category` ==> a specific product category
- `limit` ==> the default number of products to be displayed
- `columns` ==> the default number of columns.

The code:

```
// Only for Woocommerce version 3.2 and higher (3.2+)
add_shortcode("cat_sale_prod", "get_category_on_sale_products");
function get_category_on_sale_products( $atts ) {
    global $post;

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'limit'    => '12',
            'columns'  => '4',
            'category'  => '',
        ),
        $atts, 'cat_sale_prod');

    $limit   = $atts['limit'];
    $columns = $atts['columns'];

    // Get product categories
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ));
    $term  = reset($terms);

    return do_shortcode( "[products limit='$limit' columns='$columns' on_sale='true' category='$term']" );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Usage** example with a specific product category:

```
[cat_sale_prod category="clothing"]
```

Comment: No it didnt work  it still shows all the sales and my woocommerce is latest version .

Comment: @NajdDergham Sorry but for me it works on Woocommerce versions 3.2.x and 3.3.x

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce come with some shortcodes that can be used to add custom content to your pages.

The [products] shortcode allows you to display products by post ID, SKU, categories, attributes, with support for pagination, random sorting and product tags, **replacing** the need for multiples shortcodes such as:

```
[featured_products]
[sale_products]
[best_selling_products] 
[recent_products] 
[product_attribute]
[top_rated_products]
```

So you can use the [products] shortcode in conjunction with some attributes and to show the products on sale in your category, you can simply use something like this

```
[products  category ="slug-of-your-cat" on_sale="true" ]
```

for more references go to:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: While this may be the right answer, please edit and add some explanation/details so that others can understand how it solves the Question.